# Why $e^kn^k<k^ke^{\frac {n-k}{2^k}}$ whenever $n \geq k^2 2^k \ln 2 (1+o(1)) $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

Let $k$ be a natural number. I want to find a "good" (low) value of $n(k)$ which satisfies $e^kn^k<k^ke^{\frac {n-k}{2^k}}$.

I read that an answer is $n  \geq k^2 2^k \ln 2 (1+o(1)) $, where the little o is as a function of $k$. Heuristically this is since the $2^k$ cancel and we are left with $\approx e^{k^2}$ which is larger than the term $n^k \approx k^{2k} 2^{k^2}$.

How do I show this more rigorously?  <s>And why is the $\ln2$ necessary?</s>

If we write $n=k+2^kk^2\ln 2$ (which is of the requested form), we are left with showing that $e^k (k+2^k k^2\ln2)^k \leq k^k2^{k^2}$ for all $k$, which seems false since the LHS is at least $2^{k^2}(k^2 \ln2)^k$, so this easy choice of the $o(1)$ term does not work.

**EDIT**

User Clement C. explained (thanks) that the heuristic explanation for the optimality of the constant $\ln 2$ (which makes $n$ smaller) is that this translates the base in the dominant term $e^{k^2}$ to $2^{k^2}$, same as the left hand side.

Comment: The $\ln 2$ will come from the fact that there is a $2^k = e^{k\ln 2}$ in the inequality you want to establish.

Answer (score 1):

$e^kn^k<k^ke^{\frac {n-k}{2^k}}$
is equivalent to
$en<ke^{\frac {n/k-1}{2^k}}
$
or
$\ln n+1
\lt \ln k+\frac {n/k-1}{2^k}
$.

Let $m = n/k$.
This becomes
$\ln m+\ln k+1
\lt \ln k+\frac {m-1}{2^k}
$
or
$\ln m+1
\lt \frac {m-1}{2^k}
$.

Let $r = 2^k$.
This now is
$\ln m+1
\lt \frac {m-1}{r}
$
or
$r
\le \frac{m-1}{\ln m +1}
$.

The right side looks like
$\frac{m}{\ln m}$,
and it is known that
the solution to
$x =\frac{m}{\ln m}$
is about
$m 
= x\ln x
$.

Let's look at
$r
= \frac{m-1}{\ln m +1}
$
or
$m
=r(\ln m +1)+1
$.
I'll treat this as an iteration
for $m$.

Let
$m_0
=r \ln r
$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
m_1
&=r(\ln m_0 +1)+1\\
&=r(\ln (r \ln r) +1)+1\\
&=r(\ln r+\ln \ln r +1)+1\\
&\approx r(\ln r+\ln \ln r +1)\\
&= m_2\\
\end{array}
$

Writing this
in terms of $n$ and $k$,
$m = n/k$ and
$r = 2^k$
so
$n/k
\approx 2^k(k\ln 2+\ln(k \ln 2) +1)
$
or

$\begin{array}\\
n
&\approx k2^k(k\ln 2+\ln k +\ln\ln 2 +1)\\
&= k^22^k\ln 2(1+\frac{\ln k +\ln\ln 2 +1}{k \ln 2})\\
&= k^22^k\ln 2(1+\frac{\ln k}{k \ln 2}+O(\frac1{k}))\\
\end{array}
$

As to the error in this,
I don't feel like
grinding through any more.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I cannot produce a rigorous proof of the claim from it, though. This answer provides the leading term of the unknown $o(1)$ term using some methods that look heuristics to me; is the iteration a formal proof or an indication of what should be the term? Is formally proving such a thing considered "not interesting"? (How can I be sure of the argument's correctness, then?)